# How to query table when table name has hyphen in Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am attempting to query a table that has a hyphen in it.

I have tried backticks and quotes (`, ', ") and they don't work.

Query

`select * from hubspot.contacts__form-submissions`

Error message:

`Error running query: syntax error at or near "-" LINE 7: from hubspot.contacts__form-submissions ^`

I don't have write permissions so I can't rename the table.

Any suggestions on how I can query this?

Comment: How was the External Table created in Redshift Spectrum? Did it come via AWS Glue? Might help: [Names and identifiers - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
select * from hubspot."contacts__form-submissions";
```

Comment: This is awesome and should be a accepted answer.